# Using traits in Laravel with different relationships for models

Tags: laravel, relationship, traits, laravel-10

My Laravel 10 application has models, each of which can change the current status. The status of each model is stored in a table.

```
class Cat extends Model
{
    public function status()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CatStatus::class);
    }

    public function latestStatus()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(CatStatus::class)->latestOfMany();
    }
}

class Dog extends Model
{
    public function status()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(DogStatus::class);
    }

    public function latestStatus()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(DogStatus::class)->latestOfMany();
    }
}
```

To eliminate the same code in models (setting the status, getting the last status, etc.) I want to use traits. In this case, how is it correct to transfer the relation for each model to the trait?

Right now, I have two ideas.

1. Create a constant in the trait with the relation `Model` - `ModelStatus` and get the value in the method:

   ```php
   trait Statusable
   {
       const FOR_MODELS = [
           Cat::class => CatStatus::class,
           Dog::class => DogStatus::class
       ];
   }
   ```
2. Get `ModelStatus` via a method on the `Model`

   ```php
   class Cat extends Model
   {
       protected $modelStatus = CatStatus::class;

       public function nameModelStatus()
       {
           return $this->modelStatus;
       }
   }
   ```

Which option is better to choose? Or is there another better option?

Comment: "Better" is a subjective term; do you mean better in terms of performance? Code readability/maintainability? etc. These kinds of questions are generally considered off-topic for Stackoverflow (which is not the say they are bad questions, just not a good fit for SO's technical Question and Answer format). One thought, you could have `nameModelStatus()` as a trait that accesses `$modelStatus`, which would let you use the Trait on any model, as long as `protected $modelStatus` is defined on it, but that would be my opinion, not an answer per-se.

Comment: I have a better solution for you, if you have to have "statuses" and other stuff, repeated over some models, it means you do not have your data correctly normalized... In this case, you could define a single relationship (`status`, then define latest), but use `morphOne`, and just use a single table where you put the status and another column where you put the model you are setting the status for, that is 100% a [`morphable`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships) relationship

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly defining the relationship in the trait, you can create a method in the trait that returns the relationship. Each model can then override this method to provide its own relationship implementation.

```
trait Statusable
{
    public function status()
    {
        return $this->hasMany($this->statusModel());
    }

    public function latestStatus()
    {
        return $this->hasOne($this->statusModel())->latestOfMany();
    }

    protected function statusModel()
    {
        // Default implementation, can be overridden in each model
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can override the `statusModel()` method to retrieve and return the desired status model class in your models.

```
class Cat extends Model
{
    use Statusable;

    protected function statusModel()
    {
        return CatStatus::class;
    }
}

class Dog extends Model
{
    use Statusable;

    protected function statusModel()
    {
        return DogStatus::class;
    }
}
```